# Click handler losing reference to "this" object that created it

Tags: javascript, oop

I made JS script:

```
var zzz;
zzz = {
    fff: function (Id) {
        alert("You did it! Id="+Id);
    },
    main: function (Id) {
        var button, elements;
        button = document.createElement("input");
        button.type = "submit";
        button.onclick = function () {
            zzz.fff(Id);
        };
        elements = document.getElementById(Id);
        elements.appendChild(button);
    }
};
```

and HTML, where I tested it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>My Web Page!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="div001"></div>
        <div id="div002"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            object1 = zzz;
            object1.main("div001");
            object2 = zzz;
            object2.main("div002");
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Why it works only if I write `button.onclick = function () { zzz.fff(Id); };` and with `this.fff(Id)` it doesn't work?

Comment: `this` would be in the scope of `main`. Hence it would not work

Comment: MDN has a great section on `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: It's not about scope. The value of `this` inside a function is determined dynamically when the function is called, and depends on how it's called. In your case, it's being called by the browser as an event handler, and `this` gets set to the DOM node that triggered the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind an event handler (such as `onclick`), inside the handler `this` becomes the element that triggered the event (except if you used an inline `onclick=""` attribute, which should be avoided).

Instead of using `zzz`, you could also copy `this` to another variable that would be available inside the handler via closure:

```
var that = this;
button.onclick = function () {
    that.fff(Id);
};
```

Or you could use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var clickHandler = button.onclick = function () {
    this.fff(Id);
};
button.onclick = clickHandler.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thank you.

Will read about `Function.prototype.bind` too. It seems more universal.

Comment: @IlmārsCīrulis It's not supported by older browsers, but the MDN page includes a (simplified) shim.